# how can i stop a running webserver other than apache on linux?

Tags: php, mysql, apache, webserver

I'm a beginner webdev using linux. I installed Xamp in my ubuntu 18.04 LTS. But when i make  `**sudo /opt/lampp/lampp start**` so as to start apache, apache doesn't start. I tried to see if another webserver is running on the port 80 by tapping `**telnet localhost 80**` and remarked that another webserver is running. But i don't know how to stop it and get apache running in lieu of it. Of course i did a google search but i'm not getting a helping answer to my question. Does anybody know how i can fix my problem and get apache running ? thanks for helping

Comment: First try service apache2 status  and see hwat responds on _http://127.0.0.1

Comment: Try `lsof -i :80` to find out what process is using port 80

Comment: Tried service apache2 status and it said that apache2 is running. Perhaps it's the reason why Xampp can't make it start again. Howerver the command lsof -i :80 didn't give any output. Does it mean that no service is running on port 80 ?

Comment: thank you guies. Fixed it. I stopped the service apache2 by tapping systemctl stop apache2.service. Then tried sudo /opt/lampp/lampp start and Xamp's apache started. Thanks for your help.

Comment: as you are going to continue with Xamp, suggest `systemctl disable apache2.service` to prevents its automatic startup.

Comment: @danblack, that is the best thing to do here. Or you can change the port on which the apache2 (ubuntu-package) runs at. But that is a bit complicated. So, you could go with disabling it from starting automatically by running the mentioned command. Also, I am pretty sure it is not Xamp, but it is XAMPP

Comment: Thanks you very much @danblack. I'm going to do what you said.

Comment: You're right about the spelling of Xampp. It's not Xamp but Xampp. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**hello,**

Sometimes you need to stop/start it from the bin/ folder. 
You have to check where exactly your apache is installed.
For example if you installed apache in "/usr/local/apache2/". You have to start/stop the server as follow :

$cd /usr/local/apache2/bin/
$ sudo ./apachectl -k stop

if you want to start ==> replace stop by strat

**I hope this can help you ;)**